# Is there a way to check registry definitions in Forefront on remote systems?

Tags: windows-registry, microsoft-forefront, cscript

After playing with the script found in [This Thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/230368/timestamp-of-last-definition-update-for-microsoft-security-essentials-via-script) yesterday, I found that the script did exactly what I was looking for. However, I need to run these checks on remote systems on our network. I spent a few hours altering the script, but could not get it to run on the checks against the specified computers. I'm quite new to scripting, so I'm probably not seeing the glaring mistake. Can anyone assist with this? Any assistance would be much appreciated.

When ran, the script does not break with any errors. It does prompt for a system name, which is intended and will break if the name is incorrect or the system is not online. If the specified machine is online, the script will proceed to echo values. However, the values that are returned are of the local system and not of the remote.

```
 strInput = UserInput( "Enter System Name:" )
 WScript.Echo "You entered: " & strInput

 Function UserInput( myPrompt )
     If UCase( Right( WScript.FullName, 12 ) ) = "\CSCRIPT.EXE" Then
                WScript.StdOut.Write myPrompt & " "
         UserInput = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine
     Else
        UserInput = InputBox( myPrompt )
     End If
 End Function

 strComputer = strInput
 Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
  & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
 'Option Explicit
 FCS_REGKEY_ROOT = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware"

 Dim SCAN_KEY, SIGNATUREUPDATES_KEY
 Dim AV_VERSION_VALUE, AS_VERSION_VALUE, ENGINE_VERSION_VALUE, AV_DATE, AS_DATE
 Dim LAST_SCAN_TIME, LAST_SCAN_TYPE, INSTALL_PATH_VALUE
 SCAN_KEY=FCS_REGKEY_ROOT & "\Scan"
 SIGNATUREUPDATES_KEY = FCS_REGKEY_ROOT & "\Signature Updates"
 INSTALL_PATH_VALUE= FCS_REGKEY_ROOT & "\InstallLocation"
 AV_VERSION_VALUE= SIGNATUREUPDATES_KEY &"\AVSignatureVersion"
 AS_VERSION_VALUE= SIGNATUREUPDATES_KEY &"\ASSignatureVersion"
 ENGINE_VERSION_VALUE= SIGNATUREUPDATES_KEY &"\EngineVersion"
 AV_DATE= SIGNATUREUPDATES_KEY &"\AVSignatureApplied"
 AS_DATE= SIGNATUREUPDATES_KEY &"\ASSignatureApplied"
 LAST_SCAN_TIME= SCAN_KEY & "\LastScanRun"
 LAST_SCAN_TYPE= SCAN_KEY & "\LastScanType"



 '************ MAIN ************
 Dim AV_Version, AS_Version, EngineVersion, ProductVersion
 Dim AV_BuildDate, AS_BuildDate, LastScanTime, LastScanType
 Dim objShell
 set objShell      = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")


 '============ Get current info ============
 AV_Version = objShell.RegRead(AV_VERSION_VALUE)
 AS_Version = objShell.RegRead(AS_VERSION_VALUE)
 EngineVersion = objShell.RegRead(ENGINE_VERSION_VALUE)
 AV_BuildDate = BinaryToDate( objShell.RegRead(AV_DATE) )
 AS_BuildDate = BinaryToDate( objShell.RegRead(AS_DATE) )
 ProductVersion = GetProductVersion(INSTALL_PATH_VALUE)
 LastScanTime = BinaryToDate( objShell.RegRead(LAST_SCAN_TIME) )
 LastScanType = GetScanType( objShell.RegRead(LAST_SCAN_TYPE) )

 '============  Display summary info ============
 WScript.echo "Microsoft Forefront Client Security version:  " & ProductVersion
 WScript.echo "Engine version:  " & EngineVersion
 WScript.echo "Antivirus Definition:  Version " & AV_Version & " created on " & AV_BuildDate
 WScript.echo "Antispyware Definition:  Version " & AS_Version & " created on " & AS_BuildDate
 WScript.echo "Last scan:  " & LastScanTime & " (" & LastScanType & ")"

 '************ END MAIN ************


 '===============================================================
 'Function BinaryToDate will covert a binary DATE_TIME structure into a Variant date set to the local time
 '  Parameter: bArray - a VARIANT array of bytes
 '  Return: a VARIANT date
 Function BinaryToDate(bArray)
 dim Seconds,Days,dateTime
 Set dateTime = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")
  Seconds       = bArray(7)*(2^56) + bArray(6)*(2^48) + bArray(5)*(2^40) + bArray(4)*(2^32) _
                      + bArray(3)*(2^24) + bArray(2)*(2^16) + bArray(1)*(2^8) + bArray(0)
  Days            = Seconds/(1E7*86400)
  dateTime.SetVarDate   CDate(DateSerial(1601, 1, 1) + Days ), false
  BinaryToDate = dateTime.GetVarDate ()
 End Function

 '===============================================================
 'Function GetProductVersion will query a registry key for the file location and then return the version from the filesystem
 '  Parameter: strRegPath - path to the registry pointing to the installation location
 '  Return: a VARIANT string containing the product version
 Function GetProductVersion(regPath)
  const FILE_TO_CHECK = "\msmpeng.exe"
  dim strFilePath, objFSO
  strFilePath = objShell.RegRead(regPath) & FILE_TO_CHECK
  Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  GetProductVersion = objFSO.GetFileVersion(strFilePath)
  Set objFSO = Nothing
 End Function

 '===============================================================
 'Function GetScanType will return a string with the scan type that corresponds to the enum
 '  Parameter: iScanType - type of scan
 '  Return: a VARIANT string containing text type of scan
 Function GetScanType(iScanType)
  Select case(iScanType)
    Case 1 : GetScanType= "Quick Scan"
    Case 2 : GetScanType= "Full Scan"
    Case Else GetScanType= "Invalid Scan type"
  End Select
 End Function
```

Comment: Could you be any more specific than *"could not get it to run on the checks against the specified computers"* -- were there any errors? Did it not do what you expected? What did it do? Please edit your question to include any relevant details. :)

Comment: Post edited. Sorry for not providing enough detail and thank you for bringing that to my attention. Let me know if any other information would be useful. :)